# Report on how many have been converted from an unqualified to a qualified lead

Tags: report, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am very new to CRM development; I would appreciate if anyone can help me to create below report in Micosoft CRM online.

> “A report to Report on how many have been converted from an unqualified to a qualified lead in the past week”

Is this anything that I can do with report wizard or report server as well? The problem is that I don’t know how can I can I access the status converted date of a lead.  I cannot see any field regarding this in lead entity.

The simplest way of creating report in Dynamic CRM is using a report wizard.
When a lead marked as qualified it will be  closed and will be converted to another entity like opportunity / contact and so on.
The first solution that comes to mind is using report wizard on lead entity and filter in `status=”qualified”`, then choose a column like converted date in the report.

But there is not any field in lead entity that you can use for this purpose.

I need a workaround to retrieve this information (lead converted data) to be able to make above report.

Comment: Is there some code, others might help, or is it something to click / select of what is not shown in the question? Unclear to me, how one might help based on the info, but maybe others know. If unsure, maybe edit the question to add detail or what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are heading the right direction with:

> The first solution is coming to mind is using report wizard on lead
>   entity and filter in status=”qualified”, then choose a column like
>   converted date in the report.

In terms of the field you could use:

- Make a new one, and then use a workflow to populate the field when the lead is qualified.
- Use modified on, if you are sure nothing else will modify the lead after it is qualified.
- Use the created on date of the qualified opportunity linked to the lead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solutions. All of then was good. I have used the solution 2, it was easier and I'm sure that after qualifying lead, it would be closed and disable for editing.